# How to generate a new CSRF token on every request without sacrificing usability or security?

Tags: security, csrf, breach-attack

[This article](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/raising-the-csrf-bar/) suggests that we should be changing our CSRF tokens on every request to prevent a BREACH attack. i.e., if we use gzip/brotli and per-session CSRF tokens, and SSL, our tokens are vulnerable with only 1000 requests.

Supposing that's true, how would one go about regenerating a CSRF token on every request without breaking back/forward and multiple tabs?

The obvious solution is to store an array of valid CSRF tokens in our session instead of just the most recent one, perhaps limiting it to 100 or so.

But what if we used a JWT or something instead? We could store just the user ID in there, then validate that the token isn't expired and it belongs to the current user, and we wouldn't need to store it on the server at all. The only problem is that we couldn't revoke the CSRF-JWT when the user logs out, which would necessitate a short expiry, but we wouldn't want it too short or it'd expire before the user has a chance to submit the form.

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JWT and send it as a Bearer token in the header and store it in local storage. Do NOT send it in a cookie. Send it on every request and check the validity of it on every request. You can give the user a refresh token that you can revoke when they log out. The refresh token will generate access JWTs that expire after a very short period for each call.

You can use the JWT for access control and all your authorization needs.

Comment: Why not send it in a cookie..? Wait.. why would I store it at all if I'm discarding it on every request? It just needs to be stuffed into a hidden input on my form, like normal.

Comment: If it is in a cookie then you are at risk for CSRF if you don't add a nonce. You don't have to store the token at every request, but you could keep the token live for multiple requests. You do have to store the refresh token. The token is time based so you do not want to put in in a hidden field, unless you are only using it as a nonce.

Comment: Why do I have to store a refresh token? Refresh tokens are useful for APIs, but that's not what I'm building here. I'm giving them a fresh token on every request -- the user doesn't need to refresh the token themselves. If i'm not putting the token in a hidden field, and I'm not putting in the cookie... how am I supposed to get the token back when the user submits a form...? CSRFs need to be submitted with the form. They're not nonces either -- JWTs remain valid until they expire.